# Use an array of middlewares at express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to use an array of middlewares. Well, more like a combination of function names and arrays.

Instead of having:

```
router.post('/editPassword', validate, changePassword, sendConfirmation);
```

I would like to have something like:

```
router.post('/editPassword', validate, [changePassword, sendConfirmation] );
```

That would look like:

```
router.post('/editPassword', validate, doAction );
```

Where `doAction` would be an array like this:

```
var doAction = [
   //equivalent of changePassword
   function(req, res, next){
      //whatever
      next();
   },

   //equivalent to the previous sendConfirmation
   function(req, res, next){
      //whatever
   }
]
```

But it seems it is failing and going back to the `validate` step after the `next()` within the first function in `doAction`.

I'm looking for a way to simplify the middleware chaining including some middleware steps under the same name.

Comment: Have you tried putting `validate` in the array as well just for testing purposes?

Comment: Can you explain _"going back to the `validate` step"_? Does it call that middleware again?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. It seems to be working totally fine. 
I forgot a return statement after a `next()`. So... now I wonder, why using compose-middleware then if this works just fine?

Answer (score 5):

I assume the reason you wanted it to look that way is not only for it to appear presentable, but also to be able to reuse the other middleware. In that case, you can create a middleware which runs all other middlewares to do the check for you, and only calls the next function if all validations succeed.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

function middleware1(req, res, next) {
    if(req.query.num >= 1) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.json({message: "failed validation 1"});
    }
}

function middleware2(req, res, next) {
    if(req.query.num >= 2) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.json({message: "failed validation 2"});
    }
}

function middleware3(req, res, next) {
    if(req.query.num >= 3) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.json({message: "failed validation 3"});
    }
}

function combination(req, res, next) {
    middleware1(req, res, function () {
        middleware2(req, res, function () {
            middleware3(req, res, function () {
                next();
            })
        })
    })
}


app.get('/', combination, function (req, res) {
  res.send('Passed All Validation!');
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

You can test this app by running it then viewing `http://localhost:3000/?num=3`, changing the value 3 to a lower number, or removing the num parameter.

I'm not sure if this is the proper way to do it, but this is how I've handled my other projects. Let me know what you think.

**note**: see comments for use case. @robertklep may have a better solution depending on how you want to use middlewares

Comment: `combination` basically does what Express already does internally when you pass multiple middleware functions (in an array or not) on a route handler. So it's similar to `app.get(..., middleware1, middleware2, middleware3)`.

Comment: @robertklep yes, but if you have multiple routes that use that sequence and decide to later on change the combination pattern, you can do that within the combination middleware instead of finding and changing every route that uses it.

Comment: In that case, do this: `let combination = [ middleware1, middleware2, middleware3 ]`, and use just `combination` instead of passing the three functions separately.

Comment: @robertklep that's what I had in mind earlier. I guess my answer will only make sense if you need more validation than the other middlewares provide. Like using a 3rd party middleware you have no control over.

Answer (score 5):

Latest version of Express can handle this:

```js
function logOriginalUrl (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Request URL:', req.originalUrl)
  next()
}

function logMethod (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Request Type:', req.method)
  next()
}

var logStuff = [logOriginalUrl, logMethod]
app.get('/user/:id', logStuff, function (req, res, next) {
  res.send('User Info')
})
```

You can review more from [this link](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.application)

Answer (score 3):

Just search a little more ^^ : Less ugly and more understandable than previous answer

https://github.com/blakeembrey/compose-middleware

Comment: Just noticed it was a bug in my side. So... now I wonder, why using `compose-middleware` then if this works just fine? What's the advantage?

Comment: The advantage is to easily compose middleware for reuse (for example inside an expressjs project : you use 2 middleware that have both another middleware behind them, also useful for another projects ). You have also the control to call next if middleware2 fails and middleware3 is called only if middleware2 succeded)

Answer (score 2):

Be careful that you're not doing (the equivalent of) this in your `validate` middleware:

```
function middleware(req, res, next) {
  if (someCondition) {
    console.log('some condition is true');
    next();
  }
  console.log('some condition is false');
  res.status(400).end();
}
```

The intention here is that after calling `next` the rest of the code isn't executed, but it will. There's nothing really special about `next`, so when you call it, after it returns the middleware code continues to run (causing both *"some condition is true"* and *"some condition is false"* to be logged).

That's why you often see this:

```
  if (someCondition) {
    console.log('some condition is true');
    return next();
    // Or, alternatively:
    // next();
    // return;
  }
```

The `return` causes the middleware function to return after calling `next`, so the rest of the code in the function won't be executed.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is already built into express as an array or middleware:

```js
let combined = express.Router()
    .use(
        [
            middleware1,
            middleware2,
            middleware3,
        ],
    );
```

```js
let combined = express.Router()
    .use(
        middleware1,
        middleware2,
        middleware3,
    );
```

## Full Example

```js
"use strict";

let Http = require("http");
let Express = require("express");

let server = Express();
let app = Express.Router();
let combined = Express.Router();

combined.use(
    function (req, res, next) {
        console.log("huzzah!");
        next();
    },
    function (req, res, next) {
        res.json({ success: true });
    }
);

function middleware0(req, res, next) {
    console.log('ground zero');
    next();
}

app.get("/combined", middleware0, combined);
server.use("/", app);

Http.createServer(server).listen(3000);
```