# Returning an array of middleware from another middleware in express JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a route to view the information of a shop. The route looks like

```
router.param('userId',getUserById)
router.get("/store/:storeName/:userId?",isAuthenticated,getStoreDetail)
```

Based on the condition I want to send a response. In the route the `userId` is optional. If the `userId` is not provided it sends only particular information of the shop as a response. And if the `userId` is provided then I should authenticate the user and then send all the details of the shop.

So I created a middleware to achieve this.

```
const isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
    const { user } = req
    if (user) {
        return [
            expressJwt(jwtTokenProperty),
            (err, req, res, next) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(401).json({
                        status: false,
                        error: err.message,
                        isJWTError: true
                    })
                }
                const checker = req.user && req.auth && req.user.id == req.auth.id
                if (!checker) {
                    return res.status(401).json({
                        status: false,
                        error: "Invalid Request"
                    })
                }
                next()
            }
        ]
    } else {
        next()
    }
}
```

If the `userId` is not provided then I am getting a response as needed. But if the `userId` is provided I don't get any response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to `return next()`.

Edit: You need to return a response rather than array containing a function.

```
const isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
    const { user } = req
    return user
        ? [expressJwt(jwtTokenProperty), processResponse(req, res, next)]
        : next()
}

const processResponse = (req, res, next) => {
    const checker = req.user && req.auth && req.user.id == req.auth.id
    if (!checker) {
        return res.status(401).json({
            status: false,
            error: "Invalid Request"
        })
    }
    return next()
}
```

Comment: It's not working. My question is if there exists a user I should check whether he is a valid user and then send the response

Comment: Now that I look at it your code does seem curious. You're returning a middleware? I'm not sure a middleware (which is a function of three parameters) is valid to return.

Comment: I too had the same doubt. But I referred to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47572752/calling-a-middleware-from-within-a-middleware-in-nodejs-expressjs.

Comment: Oh but they're calling the middleware with arguments, not returning it! That's a difference! I've split it out and updated the example. :)

Comment: when we call processResponse() I am getting `err` is not defined. If I try to add `err` parameter to `isAuthenticated` then in the next middleware I am not able to access `req` parameter

Comment: That makes sense, in that case though just drop the err message. Or hardcode one. The ```(err, req, res, res) => { //stuff }``` lambda, is meant for the error handler, and sticking it in the middleware section doesn't really make sense. Figuring out if an error in the middlelayer is your job. Try getting rid of the first if statement. I've updated the example.

Comment: Can you clear my doubt. In this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42859020/use-an-array-of-middlewares-at-express-js there using array of middlewares in route. So according to my quesion, If I return array of middlewares why it is not working?